# Appearance of reflection of Point Light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, reflection

I've been using Point Lights to give light to some candles.
But how do I get the reflections in the window to appear better/nicer using Cycles? They're just yellow blobs as you can see:

[image]

Comment: Well, you could decrease the radius, but in the meantime if you’re using cycles, why not just use volumetric fire to emit light realistically?

Comment: Isn't volumetric fire a bit too much effort for this scene especially when it should be a still image maybe and no animation? I definitely agree on decreasing the radius. Why not model a small simple flame and give it an emission shader? Then maybe disable shadow visibility so it doesn't block the point light. Or delete the point lights and use the flame's emission.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would be to decrease the radius of the point light through the point light settings
[image]

This will make that yellow blob pretty much disappear but if you want it to look like its actually fire, you have to give an emission shader to the fire